# Horror novel involving teenagers killed at a beach party for their part in another's (accidental) death

Tags: identification-request

I think I read this 5 years ago as an ebook from the library. I'm 99% certain it's not an R.L. Stine or Christopher Pike book. There were no paranormal aspects to it, just a determined killer. A group of teenagers gather at the beach house of a wealthy friend who's a bit of a jerk, and is always pulling pranks and elaborate stunts. I remember that there was something involving coffins in the presentation with everyone getting clues (and weapons?) for a scavenger hunt with the promise of a prize. They all split up, and bit by bit, you see them getting picked off by the killer, with the teenagers being unsure as to what's real and what's part of the game. I think the person running the party is eventually found dead in one of the coffins, and shortly thereafter, they realize that the area is doused in an accelerant (gasoline?) and they have to escape a fire.

In one of the other scenes, they realize that the deaths are real because they find body parts (fingers?) of one of the guests. I also remember there's a scene where they find a set of underground passages with one terminating in a cave full of goods (drugs?) used by a smuggler (not actually tied to the murder plot).

Ultimately, the killer is revealed, as well as their motivation:

> A girl, maybe his sister, died a few years back because she was working at a country club, and got locked in as a prank by the teenagers being killed. It was a cold night, and she only realized she was locked in after leaving the pool and finding her clothes missing, and she dies from exposure. The prank was not meant to be deadly, but something went awry (forgot to leave the keys? Her cell phone accidentally got soaked? I don't recall).

I think the killer was one of the teenagers thought to have been taken out, meaning no one suspected them. I don't remember much about the riddles/clues they were supposed to solve, but I think the clues gradually became more and more pointed about their guilt and complicity in the past crime, and I want to say there was a recurring theme of them being told that they'd "broken the rules".

Answer (score 10, accepted):

*The Rules* by Nancy Holder and Debbie Viguié

Description from [goodreads.com](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/27190204-the-rules):

> It’s Saw meets I Know What You Did Last Summer in this dark thriller
> by the New York Times bestselling authors of the Wicked series.
>
> Narrated by alternating members of an unreliable group of teens, this
> riveting thriller will have readers on the edge of their seats. No one
> is safe, and everyone is a suspect.
>
> Callabrese High’s exclusive parties are famous for booze, sex, and
> most especially, their scavenger hunts. But when the latest invitees
> RSVP yes, they have no idea what they’re in for. Because this time the
> high school elite aren’t the ones doing the hunting. They’re the ones
> being hunted.